# Transition on nodes' and links' positions in D3 v4 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am using D3 v4 to make a dynamic social network visualization and an example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/wand5r6L/1/.

There are two years of data in this example, and I want to update the nodes and links when 2004 comes to 2005. I want to make the positions of nodes and links to dynamically change as new nodes and links are added, but they just pop out at once regardless of the original position of old nodes and links.

I think I should add `transition()` to the `tick()` function but it does not work and causes more bugs.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modifying a force layout block example from Mike Bostock:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0adcc447925ffae87975a3a81628a196

This is an updated jsfiddle I forked from the one you made.  Mostly I specified a key function in the data links:

https://jsfiddle.net/eonny83k/1/

```
 var node = g2
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodeData, function(d) { return d.source + '-' + d.target });
```